# Computing $\mathsf{E}[ \log ( \mathsf{P}[U=a \mid V] ) \mid U=a]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $(U,V)$ be a pair of random variables. I am interested in the following quantity:
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[ \log ( \mathsf{P}[U=a \mid V] ) \mid U=a]
\end{align}
where $a$ is some fixed constant.  For simplicity, assume $U$ is a discrete random variable.

We know that log is concave so if we use Jensen's inequality we have that
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[ \log ( \mathsf{P}[U=a \mid V] ) \mid U=a] &\le   \log ( 
 \mathsf{E}\left[ \mathsf{P}[U=a \mid V] \mid U=a\right] ) \\
&=\log ( 
  \mathsf{P}\left[U=a  \mid U=a\right] )\\
&=\log ( 
 1 )=0
\end{align}

Using Jensen's inequality we can also arrive at the following lower bound
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[ \log ( \mathsf{P}[U=a \mid V] ) \mid U=a] &= \mathsf{E}[ \log ( \mathsf{E}[1_{ \{U=a \}} \mid V] ) \mid U=a]\\
&\ge \mathsf{E}[ \mathsf{E}[  \log ( 1_{ \{U=a \}}  )  \mid V]\mid U=a]\\
&= \mathsf{E}[   \log ( 1_{ \{U=a \}})  \mid U=a]\\
&=0. 
\end{align}

Using the two bounds we conclude that
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[ \log ( \mathsf{P}[U=a \mid V] ) \mid U=a]=0.
\end{align}

However, I think there must be something wrong here. I don't think this is correct, but I cannot find an error.

Comment: Can you explain this step? $$\mathsf{E}[ \mathsf{E}[  \log ( 1_{ \{U=a \}}  )  \mid V]\mid U=a]
= \mathsf{E}[   \log ( 1_{ \{U=a \}})  \mid U=a]$$ (I believe this is where your error lies)

Comment: As a second issue, is $\log ( \mathsf{P}[U=a \mid V] )$ even integrable in your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trace through your argument under the simplifying assumption that $V$ is a constant random variable. You'll find that the following assertion is not true:

$$\log(\mathsf{E}\left[ \mathsf{P}[U=a \mid V] \mid U=a\right] )
=\log ( 
  \mathsf{P}\left[U=a  \mid U=a\right] )\tag1$$
since the LHS equals $\log[ P(U=a)]$ when $V$ is constant; and
$$\mathsf{E}[ \mathsf{E}[  \log ( 1_{ \{U=a \}}  )  \mid V]\mid U=a]
= \mathsf{E}[   \log ( 1_{ \{U=a \}})  \mid U=a]\tag2$$
is also false since the LHS equals $-\infty$ when $V$ is constant and $P(U=a)>0$.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I am using the towering property wrong.